# Rails - relation to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Every instance of the model market can have a supermarket and a submarket.
I added the following code in the market model.

```
  has_one :market, as: submarket
  belongs_to :market, as: supermarket
```

I also created a migration

```
  def change
    add_column :markets, :supermarket_id, :integer
  end
```

However, I still get errors:

```
:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `submarket' for #<Class:0x007fda225fac40> (NameError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup self-join:

```
has_one :submarket, class_name: "Market", foreign_key: :supermarket_id
belongs_to :supermarket, class_name: "Market", foreign_key: :supermarket_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define `submarket` association on `has_one`. Also, you're misusing options. It should be:

```
has_one :submarket, foreign_key: 'supermarket_id', class_name: 'Market'
belongs_to :market, foreign_key: 'supermarket_id'
```

if you want to have your 'belongs_to' association named `supermarket` instead of `market`, it's easy too:

```
belongs_to :supermarket, foreign_key: 'supermarket_id', class_name: 'Market'
```